# Modal window semantic-ui-react from example not opening

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I got code of modal from [example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-basic):

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ModalBasicExample = () => (
    <Modal trigger={<Button>Basic Modal</Button>} basic size='small'>
        <Header icon='archive' content='Archive Old Messages' />
        <Modal.Content>
            <p>
                Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?
            </p>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
            <Button basic color='red' inverted>
                <Icon name='remove' /> No
            </Button>
            <Button color='green' inverted>
                <Icon name='checkmark' /> Yes
            </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
)

export default ModalBasicExample
```

and added as component to my App.js:

```html
import React from 'react'
...
import ModalBasicExample from "./Modal";

export default class App extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                ...
                <ModalBasicExample/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Now I see a button but when I click it the modal doesn't open:

[image]

```
Dependencies:
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.85.0",
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the related stylesheet information, as well:

1. Add "semantic-ui-css" dependency via your package manager (e.g. yarn / npm):

```
yarn add semantic-ui-css
```

2. Import it in your App.js:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

That's it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l4k5428rjl